# How to customize a dynamic website in PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am working on a website to analyse energy data that I get from several remote meters. I'm using JS, PHP and mySQL. I developed the website with one client's data (specific type and numbers of remote meters). This is the first website I did, I have a lot to learn.

There are the steps:

1. Login form  // same for everyone
2. PHP check login  // same for everyone
3. Index page  // same for everyone
4. Javascript with AJAX function to post data (range of date) to a php file (calculation.php) to calculate stuff // JS file is the same for everyone
5. PHP file gets the data from mySQL and does many calculation about energy stuff, then echoes it
6. The JS file gets the data (via AJAX) and then displays graphs via google Chart library

The problem is that the PHP file that gets the AJAX POST (end of step 4 and step 5) **won't** do the same calculation for every client. So I don't know what to do, I'm a bit lost.
I thought at:

1. Putting a condition in the PHP file for every client, like "if
   client_id=X" // this seems too bad with dozens of clients
2. Writing a different PHP file for every client. Writing the name of
   this PHP file in the mysql table "clients". Doing an intermediate php
   file called by AJAX that will check the client_id against the
   database then "include" the specific PHP file into the temporary one.
3. Writing the PHP PDO request in a string type into the table
   "clients" then query it from the PHP file "calculation.php". The PHP file will do the correct command.

These solutions don't seem good to me (maybe the third?). Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT Example of php code**

**first client:**

```
$reponse1 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%H:%i') AS timekey, AVG(Value) FROM meter1 WHERE Date>='$from' AND Date<='$to' GROUP BY timekey");
$reponse1->execute();
$myArrayLP24temp1['Hour']= $reponse1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$reponse1->execute();
$myArrayLP24temp1['Value']= $reponse1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);

$reponse2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%H:%i')AS timekey, AVG(Value) FROM meter2 WHERE Date>='$from' AND Date<='$to' GROUP BY timekey");
$reponse2->execute();
$myArrayLP24temp2['Value']= $reponse2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);


for ($ii=0; $ii<24*4; ++$ii){    
    $meter1NoRound=$myArrayLP24temp1['Value'][$ii]*4;
    $meter2NoRound=$myArrayLP24temp2['Value'][$ii]*4;

    $meter1=round($meter1NoRound,1);
    $meter2=round($meter2NoRound,1);

    $myArrayLP24['rows'][]= array('c' => array( array('v'=>$myArrayLP24temp1['Hour'][$ii]), array('v'=>($meter1)), array('v'=>($meter2))));
```

**second client:**

```
$reponse1 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%H:%i') AS timekey, AVG(Value) FROM meter1 WHERE Date>='$from' AND Date<='$to' GROUP BY timekey");
$reponse1->execute();
$myArrayLP24temp1['Hour']= $reponse1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$reponse1->execute();
$myArrayLP24temp1['Value']= $reponse1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);

for ($ii=0; $ii<24*4; ++$ii){    
    $meter1NoRound=$myArrayLP24temp1['Value'][$ii]*4;

    $meter1=round($meter1NoRound,1);

    $myArrayLP24['rows'][]= array('c' => array( array('v'=>$myArrayLP24temp1['Hour'][$ii]), array('v'=>($meter1))));
```

The examples above show two differents code. The first one is for a client with two meters, the second one for a client with one meter. It can be up to 10 meters, and sometimes there will be sub meters that I will have to add up sometimes not. So the code is different for every client (except for clients with the exact same configuration, but that won't happen very often).

Comment: This is so descriptive.. How the above solutions are not good? Did you make any benchmark? PHP is slow for lengthy calculations, one path i would consider is calling a PHP file to get the required data and bring them to JS for calculation (faster) or code an executable program, then [exec](http://php.net/function.exec) it if performance is still not good, although it involves another language

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry I wasn't clear, most of the calculation is done by mySQL request (sum, average, etc.) using PDO, so in my opinion the calculation is very fast about one second for thousands of row. Actually the slowest is to display the charts, about 4 seconds. I prefer not doing calculation in JS and keeping the actual architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Why not storing the variable values in data base ?
Then, when client comes you have all the require infos to make your calculation.

Think simple and standardize the more you can.
Never forget that a good developer is a lazy person ;-)

**EDIT**

When you're saying :

"The problem is that the PHP file that gets the AJAX POST (end of step 4 and step 5) won't do the same calculation for every client."

What do you mean ?

1. The calculation formula is different for each client ?
2. The values to use in the formula are different for each client ?

The way i understood your question is in the first case.
Whatever, for both cases, store what you need in DB and use it as it comes with the client.

May be i didn't understand well what you need. If it is, please, send a piece of code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm not sure I understood what variables values you're talking about. Thanks KevOne.

Comment: I edited my question and added an example of code. The calculation formula will be different for each client AND the values to use in. Merci ;-)

Comment: Thx. I don't know anything about the logic you are working for ... but i think the simplest way is to store every single variable data into DB. Including values AND formulas. I know that it doesn't help a lot, but that's all what i can say to you.

Comment: Yes it helps, so you mean storing the whole block (eg "first client" above) as a string into the DB. Then when the client log in query this string and execute it. Right? I'll try...

Comment: Yes, you can try this way ... there is no absolute truth ;-)